# Stop input from clearing on innerHTML insert

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm working on a form that allows the user to add extra input fields by clicking a button.

It basically looks like this:

```
<div>
   <input type="text" placeholder="existing"/>
</div>

<button class="add">add</button>
```

With a little JavaScript:

```
var add = document.querySelector(".add");
var div = document.querySelector("div");

add.addEventListener('click', function () {

    div.innerHTML += '<input type="text" placeholder="new"/>';

});
```

However, I noticed that when the button is clicked - if any existing input fields have values, they get cleared.

I've been fiddling around with it for a while and can't seem to find a solution to stop this  from happening, so I'm wondering if anyone here can help.

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gxzLZ/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you try to `console.log(div.innerHTML)` you will see that the printed HTML is:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="existing"><input type="text" placeholder="new">...
```

When you type something inside the `<input>` you don't edit the input value. You need to preserve the original content and avoid to override each time the whole `div` content

Here's how I would do it: http://jsfiddle.net/gxzLZ/5/

**JS**

```
var add = document.querySelector(".add");
var div = document.querySelector("div");

add.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var input = document.createElement('input')
    input.type = "text";
    input.placeholder = "new";
    div.appendChild(input);
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Create an element, change `outerHTML` and then use `appendChild`.

```
add.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var newInput = document.createElement('input');
    newInput.outerHTML = '<input type="text" placeholder="new"/>';
    div.appendChild(newInput);

});
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/gxzLZ/4/)

Comment: I like this more than the accepted answer, to have the ability to create an element in html code.

Comment: But make sure you do `div.appendChild` before modifying the `outerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

could something like this work??

**HTML**

```
<div id="div"><input type="text" placeholder="existing" id="input"/></div>
<button class="add">add</button>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var add = document.querySelector(".add");
var div = document.querySelector("div");

add.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var cloned = document.getElementById('input').cloneNode(true);
    cloned.value = '';  // cloned will have no value
    document.getElementById('div').appendChild(cloned);
}, false);
```

I am using cloneNode to create nodes exactly the same. if you want the new added not to have any value, it could work as well

**[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/h_awk/gxzLZ/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

The values of the input boxes are getting disappeared because when you write

`div.innerHTML += '<input type="text" placeholder="new"/>';` ,

what happens is `div.innerHTML` is replaced by `div.innerHTML+'<input type="text" placeholder="new"/>'` and since the input values are not present in the HTML code they get reset.

Rather create elements like this :

`var inp = document.createElement("input");`

`inp.type="text";`

`document.body.appendChild(inp);`.