# How to use .appendChild to add div containing multiple text inputs in plain JavaScript (without JQuery)

Tags: javascript, dom-manipulation

For a current experiment I'm trying to make a dynamic contact form.  The goal is to let the users add and remove addresses, and indicate their type, by just clicking the button.

I noticed that while using `innerHTML` forms that already contained values lost their values any time a new addition or removal was used.  This seems to be the nature of `innerHTML` ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24162740/10257507) helped me understand what the problem was, and also pointed me to `appendChild`).

However I don't see how I can add a complex element, such as a `<div>` that contains multiple text `inputs` and a `button`.  Is there any way to achieve the same as what I'm doing with this, or to prevent the other forms from losing the input values without using JQuery?

I've tried to create an MCVE for this, here it is, along with a JS Fiddle to save time.

The working JS Fiddle is here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jssucks/6gtLop04/6/)

```js
var targetOutput = document.getElementById("myForm");
var addressOutput = document.getElementById("addresses");
var requiredAddress = 1;

addressRemoveButton = `<input type="button" value="Remove" name="address" onclick="removeDiv(this)">`;
addressMolecule = `<div class="content"><label>Type:</label>&#9;&#9;<input type="text" name="address['type'][]"><br>
                <label>Address Line 1:</label><input type="text" name="address['line1'][]"><br>
                <label>Address Line 2:</label><input type="text" name="address['line2'][]"><br>
                <label>City:</label><input type="text" name="address['city'][]"><br>
                <label>State:</label><input type="text" name="address['state'][]"><br>
                <label>Zipcode:</label><input type="text" name="address['zipcode'][]"><br>`

window.onload = function(event) {
  myFun('window');
}

function myFun(a) {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < requiredAddress; i++) {
    addAddress(false);

    //alert("Max: " + maxAddress + "Current: " + addressCount);
  }
}

function removeDiv(e) {
  e.parentNode.removeChild(e.previousSibling);
  e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
}

function addAddress(removable = true) {
  addressOutput.innerHTML += addressMolecule;
  if (removable == true) {
    addressOutput.innerHTML += addressRemoveButton;
  }
  addressOutput.innerHTML += `</div>`;
}
```

```html
<body onload="myFun('body')">
  <form name="myForm" id="myForm">
    <div id="addresses">
      <input type="button" id="addressButton" value="Add More" name="address" onclick="addAddress()">
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to insert another HTML string without the existing container losing its data, use `insertAdjacentHTML` instead:

```
addressOutput.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', addressMolecule);
```

```js
var targetOutput = document.getElementById("myForm");
var addressOutput = document.getElementById("addresses");
var requiredAddress = 1;

addressRemoveButton = `<input type="button" value="Remove" name="address" onclick="removeDiv(this)">`;
addressMolecule = `<div class="content"><label>Type:</label>&#9;&#9;<input type="text" name="address['type'][]"><br>
            <label>Address Line 1:</label><input type="text" name="address['line1'][]"><br>
            <label>Address Line 2:</label><input type="text" name="address['line2'][]"><br>
            <label>City:</label><input type="text" name="address['city'][]"><br>
            <label>State:</label><input type="text" name="address['state'][]"><br>
            <label>Zipcode:</label><input type="text" name="address['zipcode'][]"><br>`

window.onload = function(event) {
  myFun('window');
}

function myFun(a) {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < requiredAddress; i++) {
    addAddress(false);

    //alert("Max: " + maxAddress + "Current: " + addressCount);
  }
}

function removeDiv(e) {
  e.parentNode.removeChild(e.previousSibling);
  e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
}

function addAddress(removable = true) {
  addressOutput.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', addressMolecule);
  if (removable == true) {
    addressOutput.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', addressRemoveButton);
  }
  addressOutput.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `</div>`);
}
```

```html
<body onload="return myFun('body')">
  <form name="myForm" id="myForm">

    <div id="addresses">

      <input type="button" id="addressButton" value="Add More" name="address" onclick="addAddress()">
    </div>

  </form>
</body>
```

As you noted, it *would* probably be better to use `appendChild`. Create a `div`, populate it with the desired HTML, and append it to the container:

```
function addAddress(removable = true) {
  const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newDiv.className = 'content';
  newDiv.innerHTML = addressMolecule; 
  addressOutput.appendChild(newDiv);
  if (removable) {
    const button = addressOutput.appendChild(document.createElement('button'));
    button.outerHTML = addressRemoveButton;
  }
}
```

```js
var targetOutput = document.getElementById("myForm");
var addressOutput = document.getElementById("addresses");
var requiredAddress = 1;

addressRemoveButton = `<input type="button" value="Remove" name="address" onclick="removeDiv(this)">`;
addressMolecule = `<label>Type:</label>&#9;&#9;<input type="text" name="address['type'][]"><br>
            <label>Address Line 1:</label><input type="text" name="address['line1'][]"><br>
            <label>Address Line 2:</label><input type="text" name="address['line2'][]"><br>
            <label>City:</label><input type="text" name="address['city'][]"><br>
            <label>State:</label><input type="text" name="address['state'][]"><br>
            <label>Zipcode:</label><input type="text" name="address['zipcode'][]"><br>`

window.onload = function(event) {
  myFun('window');
}

function myFun(a) {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < requiredAddress; i++) {
    addAddress(false);

    //alert("Max: " + maxAddress + "Current: " + addressCount);
  }
}

function removeDiv(e) {
  e.parentNode.removeChild(e.previousSibling);
  e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
}

function addAddress(removable = true) {
  const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newDiv.className = 'content';
  newDiv.innerHTML = addressMolecule; 
  addressOutput.appendChild(newDiv);
  if (removable) {
    const button = addressOutput.appendChild(document.createElement('button'));
    button.outerHTML = addressRemoveButton;
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="return myFun('body')">
  <form name="myForm" id="myForm">

    <div id="addresses">

      <input type="button" id="addressButton" value="Add More" name="address" onclick="addAddress()">
    </div>

  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: thank you!  Haven't had a chance to give it a spin yet but I see what's happening in the second example and think it should work the way I'm trying to use this! :D Thank you!!